# Why is my Unity3D music player script playing my music only for one second?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a music player with Unity3D for a game project. I am having an issue with the following code:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MusicManager : MonoBehaviour {

  public AudioSource music1;
  public AudioSource music2;

  private void Start() {
    music1.Play();
  }

  private void Update() {
    if (!music1.isPlaying) {
      music2.Play();
      music1.Pause();
    }
   
    if (!music2.isPlaying) {
      music1.Play();
      music2.Pause();
    }
  }
}
```

The problem I am having is that `music1` is only played for one second and then there is a static sound. What is the problem here and how can I fix it?

Comment: Well, if your AudioSources aren't looping, you don't need to pause them when `isPlaying` is false.

Comment: Also, why don't you use a single AudioSource? If the tracks don't overlap, you would need only one AudioSource, then you could reference your AudioClips and call the method `AudioSource.PlayOneShot`.

Comment: @Daniel thank you, so far it is working. But how do I manage to get the original clip playing again after the second clip stops?

Comment: You can save it in a variable and retrieve it using `AudioSource.clip`.